# Using R to create a data table

Tags: r, datatable

I have something I would like to do in R but I don't even know how to begin. I want to create a data table, let's say 8 columns wide.

I want to set conditions for each column i.e.

Maximum of column value 10, 70, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100

Minimum of column value 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20

Sum of the row = 100

Steps of say 5.

The idea is that each column steps down until the row = 100 and then it moves to the next row.

Expected output is something like:

```
10, 70, 20, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
10, 70, 15, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0
10, 70, 15, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0  
10, 70, 15, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0 
10, 70, 15, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0 
10, 70, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5 
10, 70, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0
 10, 70, 10, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0
......
```

Once it follows this pattern for say 50,000 rows it will end the calculation.

How would I go about doing this?

Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. Here's my take based on random sampling from sections of a chi^2 (2 df) distribution.

The big problem here is that the sum of each row is not strictly 100.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

dat <- lapply(1:100, function(x) { # controls number of rows
  dat <- c(runif(1, 0, 0.01), runif(1, 0.3, 2), runif(8, 6, 20)) %>% # tune these, controls where in the distribution the values are coming from
    sort() %>%
    dchisq(df = 3) # samples from sections of a chi square distribution with 2 df
  dat <- plyr::round_any(300*dat, 5, f = round) # rounds to steps of 5 - the '300' scales the responses.
  dat
}) %>%
  as.data.table() %>%
  t()

apply(dat, 1, sum) %>%
  hist()
```